# Toggle between different views(HTML markup) with php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a webshop with woocommerce. I want to be able to switch between list and grid view. I know there's a plugin for this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-grid-list-toggle/

The problem is: I want to control the HTML in the views. The list view must have a different markup than the grid view. Is there any way to achieve this??

Thanks!

Comment: Please specify specific error that you are getting.

Comment: I'm not getting any error. I'm just wondering if there's anyway to build a toggle in php or js, to load different HTML markups

Comment: You need to use that plugin that you have provided in your question itself? Are you looking forward to do this without plugin?

Comment: Yes, I want to do this without the plugin. The plugin just uses the same HTML elements in both views. I want to load different HTML elements in both views.

Comment: You can use `AJAX` for that. Just render different HTML content and replace it with the old one.

Comment: I haven't worked with AJAX a lot. Is this possible with the .load() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't provided you code. I am posting one generic solution for this problem.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
<!-- Here, your gird or list view will come... -->
</div>

create one trigger button with id `change_view`
```

**JQUERY:**

```
<script>
$('#change_view').on('click',function(){
var which_view = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'get_view.php',
    data: {which_view : which_view},
    success: function(res){
        $("#container").html(null);
        $("#container").html(res); // res = your new view...
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is the get_view.php where the new view is located?

Comment: you can process your view on the basis of `which_view` variable. Or from here also you can call different URL. It `which_view='GRID'` then call that URL

Comment: Is it possible to use classes instead of id's?

Comment: You need unique IDs for this. You can also use classes but it's not recommended.

Comment: I can't seem to pass any php in the ajax loaded 'get_view.php' file.